# C11 Standard docs

Tags: c, standards, c11, ansi-c

Starting from this [SO protected question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) I'm trying to understand what the difference between those documents:

1. [9899 2012](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2FISO%2FIEC+9899-2012) costs `$60`
2. [9899 2011](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ISO%2fIEC+9899%3a2011) costs `$265`

As you can see those documents have very different prices and I don't know if the cheaper one is valid or is something like draft or cut copy of the real standard.

Did someone buy the INCITS one?

---

**EDIT**

As @Chqrlie pointed out: *What is the difference between the ANSI and ISO official documents available for a free and the final draft freely accessible from the official website at* [open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: An interesting extension to this question is: *What is the difference between the ANSI and ISO official documents available for a free and the final draft freely accessible from the official website at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf* ?

Comment: The one labelled 2012 probably includes differences from the 2012 Corrigendum (a correction of minor errors found after release).  The corrections made by the Corrigendum are listed at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1606.pdf

Comment: @Peter So: newer, corrected and cheaper...Too good to be true... ;)

Comment: That's assuming I'm right, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got answers from:

- Ansi

  > The **ISO/IEC 9899:2011** is the original ISO standard published by ISO.
  >   The **INCITS/ISO/IEC 9899-2012** is the domestic U.S. adoption of the ISO.
- INCITS

  > **Technically, the two standards are identical.** The US version has additional front matter to add a U.S. cover and adoption date details. Once we adopt the international standard, we can set the price based on our fee schedule, which generally results in a lesser fee than buying the ISO version.
  >
  > To provide more background on this, most INCITS technical committees hold U. S. Technical Advisory Group (TAG) relationships to ISO/IEC JTC 1 subcommittees and working groups and, to some ISO technical committees, subcommittees and working groups.
  >   Subject to a few exceptions, INCITS adopts all ISO/IEC or ISO standards that fall within its program of work as “Identical” American National Standards in accordance with the ANSI “Expedited Procedures for the Identical Adoption of an ISO or IEC standard as an American National Standard”.
  >
  > Similarly, INCITS will generally withdraw any such adopted American National Standard that has been withdrawn as an ISO/IEC or ISO International Standard.

Comment: Did they address the price discrepancy?

Comment: @2501 The sentence _which generally results in a lesser fee than buying the ISO version_ is all they wrote about price.

Comment: That's very interesting! Does it imply that a national body that participates in the ISO/IEC JTC subcommittees could possibly publish its own version (with just a different front cover I suppose) for free?

Comment: @chqrlie if `2+2 = 4`... ;)

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between the ANSI and ISO official documents available for a free and the final draft freely accessible from the official website at open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

There were several erroneous sentences in n1570 mentioning `_Alignof` for expressions, which doesn't exist. So `_Alignof` was removed from 6.3.2.1p2, p3, p4, fn. 65; and 6.7.1 fn. 121.

Note that since C11 we had a (very trivial) technical corrigendum and a whole lot of accepted defect reports that a conforming C11 compiler may implement ahead of a new TC or standard.